# tuning parameters for SMO

Tags: java, weka, svm

I'm using the following options to do SMO regression.

```
smo.setOptions(weka.core.Utils.splitOptions("-C complexity -N 0 -I \"weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved -L 0.001 -W 1 -P 1.0E-12 -T 0.001
V\" -K \"weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RBFKernel -C 250007 -G gamma\""));
```

So, I'm doing grid search here to find the optimal value of C and gamma(I'm using the RBF kernel). I loop through all the complexity and gamma values in a certain range to test its performance. The problem is that the variables in the double quote won't get evaluated(complexity and gamma), so I wonder how I can have them evaluated. And I didn't find a set-option method to set the parameters of RBFKernel directly, though I can use smo.setC(c) to set the C value. Thanks.